# Ullage control on stage shutdown?

Tags: launch, falcon-9, saturn-v, ullage

Is ullage control a thing only engine startup? Would a rocket like the Saturn V or Falcon 9 leave an engine running for a second or two longer just for ullage control?

Comment: Run an engine longer than what?

Comment: Longer than the other engines: shut down all but one engine, say, then kill that last engine after a second or two. No clue if this makes sense. I ask because I think I've read something like this is done, maybe in the context of the space shuttle, but I never paid close attention to ullage, so all I have is a vague memory that may be pure BS. Just checking if something like this is done, I guess, so I can carry on without misconceptions :D

Comment: You could do it the Soviet way, and ignite the upper stage *before* shutting down the first stage. This completely removes the ullage need, but adds a bit of complexity in interstage design.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is only done on engine *startup*.  Remember, ullage is done so that liquid propellant is fed to the engines, instead of gas bubbles.  When a tank is allowed to sit in microgravity for a significant amount of time, there is a risk of some of the gas bubbles in a partially-empty tank migrating to the tank's outlet at the bottom.  **An ullage burn at the end of engine firing would do nothing to stop this process.**  Instead, you do the ullage burn at the *start* of engine firing, to let the liquid in the tanks settle to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! Would 15s between MECO and stage-2 engine startup be too much? Or would stage the engine maybe be able to fire right away without ullage control?

Comment: @user39728: Best to use ullage in that case.  I have numbers handy for Saturn IB.  First stage engine cutoff at T+140.65, second stage engine start T+143.35.  That's *less than 3 seconds* between stages, and they *still* used ullage motors!